# How to not save a certain field in Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am updating a record via Mongoose but when I try to not include a field by not including it in the properties object the field just gets set to empty.

My model:

```
var demo = new Schema({
    name: String,
    slug: String,
    code: String,
    details: String,
    scripts: [],
    css: [],
    status: {
        type: String,
        default: "draft"
    },
    lastModifiedDate: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
    projectId: Schema.ObjectId
});
```

Where I'm saving:

```
        Demo.find({ slug: req.params.demoSlug }, function(err,demos){
            if(err){
                console.log("Error retrieving demo from db");
                res.send(500,err);
                return;
            }
            demos[0].update({ _id:req.params.id },{
                name: data.demoName,
                slug: Utils.createSlug(data.demoName),
                // code: data.demoCode,
                details: data.demoDetails
            }, someCallback);
    });
```

As you can see the "code" field is commented out so why is the field value being overridden? Are there any flags I need to set when

Comment: Assuming `demo` is your model class, this should work fine as according to the docs for `Model.update`: _All top level keys which are not atomic operation names are treated as set operations_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to do. You're searching for every document in a collection, but you're only updating one of them, which you're finding by `_id`. This looks like it can be done in one function, and you could be getting an error because you're calling `update` on a model that you returned. It looks like you should have written it like this:

```
Demo.update({ _id:req.params.id },{
    name: data.demoName,
    slug: Utils.createSlug(data.demoName),
    // code: data.demoCode,
    details: data.demoDetails
}, someCallback);
```

If you only want to update the document if its slug matches your `demoSlug` AND the `_id` matches, it would look like this:

```
Demo.update({ _id: req.params.id, slug: req.params.demoSlug },{
    name: data.demoName,
    slug: Utils.createSlug(data.demoName),
    // code: data.demoCode,
    details: data.demoDetails
}, someCallback);
```

If this still doesn't address your problem, hopefully it helps you explain more clearly what exactly you're looking for.

EDIT:

Another way to do this would be to use `findOne` and `save`. Try this:

```
Demo.findOne({ slug: req.params.demoSlug }, function(err, demo) {
    if(err) {
        console.log("Error retrieving demo from db");
        res.send(500, err);
        return;
    }
    demo.name = data.demoName;
    demo.slug = Utils.createSlug(data.demoName);
    demo.details = data.demoDetails;
    demo.save(callback);
}
```

Something like that should hopefully work. If neither of these work, I suspect that the problem is in `data` or in the document you're finding.

Comment: I didn't explain enough. I am retrieving the item from my database, I was just showing the Schema to show the properties incase I was doing something wrong. I've updated my post to show this.

Comment: Ok. Why are you finding all of the documents to update just one of them? If you're updating the returned documents by _id, wouldn't it be easier to just do `Demo.update({_id:req.params.id }, ...` instead? I'm thinking that doing the find separate from the update is causing unexpected behavior.

Comment: I am using a pretty URL (the 'slug' property) and so the ID is not present in the URL. Is getting demos[0] not the same as if i get demo from findById?

Comment: You're using `req.params.id` in your update call, and you are using an `id` from the params, so it appears that you're expecting to have the id. `demos[0]` and `findById` would return the same result, but you can't call `demos[0].update()` and it would be unncessary. If you want to search by the slug, just skip the find and just use `Demos.update({ slug: req.params.demoSlug }, ...` and it would do what you need.

Comment: To access the id from `demos[0]`, you should be using `demos[0]._id`.

Comment: I have tried using `Demos.update({ slug: req.params.demoSlug }` but it still overwrites the data.

Comment: Weird. I'm going to update to show you another way to do it that will hopefully work.

Comment: Sorry, my app had stop automatically restarting when I made changes. Both the update by slug and the findOne methods work. Thanks so much. I've improved my knowledge a tad!